# Django how to add multiple input type to database

Tags: django, database, input, insert

I would like to add more than one data to database by input type 'text' as code below

```
<input type="text" name= "searchmemberTaskMore"  id= "{{username}}" class="btn btn-default" value="{{username}}"/>'
```

view.py

```
def addMemberTask(request,project_url):
    dictData = getInitialVariable(request)

    if "POST" in request.method:
        if request.POST['taskSelectedAddmeberMore'] != "":
            taskSelectedAddmeberMore = request.POST['taskSelectedAddmeberMore']
        if request.POST['searchmemberTaskMore'] != "":
            searchmemberTaskMore = request.POST['searchmemberTaskMore']
        if request.POST['taskSelectedAddmeberMoreID'] != "":
            taskSelectedAddmeberMoreID = request.POST['taskSelectedAddmeberMoreID']
            object_project = projects.objects.filter(user__id=dictData["USER"].id)[0]



        object_project = projects.objects.filter(user__id=dictData["USER"].id)[0]
        t = tasks.objects.filter(id=taskSelectedAddmeberMoreID)[0]
        u = User.objects.filter(username=searchmemberTaskMore)[0]
        t.user.add(u)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/projectDetail/'+project_url)
```

How should I fix it to solve the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this why Django has a [forms framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/)?

Comment: Also, your code is prone to KeyError (what if the taskSelectedAddmeberMore isn't sent?) and your are using "in" where you should check equality (if request.method == 'POST'). The same for the querysets[0] can raise an IndexError